# What happens if an array is allocated reapeatedly in a loop and never deallocated in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I wish to know what the following code does to memory:

```
program A

While (t < large number)
 allocate(a)
 ...

end program
```

Is "allocate(a)" referring to the same memory location at each iteration, and is there memory leak if deallocate(a) before the end of the program is not used?

Comment: Is `a` declared with the `allocatable` or the `pointer` attribute?  Or do you want the answer for both cases?

Comment: You cannot allocate a program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is that it is an error to allocate an already allocated item, so this code example is erroneous.

Compilers that I tried notice the error at runtime if the item is declared as `allocatable`.  They didn't notice if the item was declared with the `pointer` attribute.  In that case you have a memory leak since memory has been reserved on earlier iterations but there is no longer a way to reach it since the pointer has been reused.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your other question, it is impossible to leak memory with `allocatable` objects. For example, allocatable arrays with a local scope are deallocated upon reaching `return` or `end` (unless they are saved), allocatable type components are automatically deallocated along with their parent, etc.

Not deallocating an object before the end of a program is not really a leak in the sense of unaddressable memory, since your program still had access to it during execution. This memory will be reported by Valgrind as "still reachable". You might consider it better style to deallocate such objects, but you don't need to.